# Place rectangle maximizing rectangle intersections

Tags: geometry, intersection, maximize, rectangles

I have this problem: given a set of rectangles {R1,R2...Rn}, and a new rectangle Rq, find where to put Rq so it intersects (it does not matter how much area) the maximum number of the rectangles in the set. I´m searching for a simple resolution not involving too complex data structures, however, any working answer will be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems that all questions that are math-related or otherwise complicated are closed as off topic. But but, if you ask a question with code with a little typo, it's newer closed. This is some sort of wasting of resources. Which one benefits more and larger audience: typocorrection or answers to a compicated problem? THINK AND THINK AND AGAIN THINK before clicking the close button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `O(n^2)` or `O(n (log n + m))` (average case only) complexity algorithm (where `m` is the maximum number of intersecting rectangles). **See `O(n log n)` method later on.**

The first idea, is to consider that there are `n` places to look for solutions. That is, for each rectangle `Ri`, the case where `Ri` is the right-most rectangle that intersects `Rq` is a candidate solution.

You will scan from left to right. Adding the rectangles in order of minimum x-coordinate to a buffer container, and also to a priority queue (based on maximum x-coordinate). As you add each rectangle, also check which rectangles need to be removed (based on the priority queue) so that the range of rectangles in the buffer can be intersected by the rectangle `Rq` if you ignore the y-axis for now.

Before adding each rectangle `Ri` to the buffer, you can consider how many rectangles in the buffer can be intersected if you require `Rq` to intersect `Ri` (with `Ri` being the right-most intersecting rectangle with `Rq`). This can be done in linear time.

Thus overall complexity is `O(n^2)`.

The runtime of the algorithm can be improved, by using an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) for any rectangle nodes stored in the buffer. Since Wikipedia gives a good amount of information on this, and how it may be implemented, I will not explain how it works here, particularly because the balancing of it can be quite complex. This will improve the average complexity to `O(n (log n + m))`, where `m` is the answer - the maximum number of intersecting rectangles (which could still be as large as `n` in the worst case). This is due to the algorithmic complexity of querying an interval tree (`O(log n + m)` time per query). The worst case is still `O(n^2)`, because `m` for the number of results returned (for interval trees), may be up to `O(n)`, even if the answer is not on the order of `n`.

---

### Here follows a method with `O(n log n)` time, but is quite complex.

Instead of storing rectangles as a sorted array, self balancing binary search tree (based on only minimum y), or an interval tree, the rectangles can also be stored in a custom data structure.

Consider the self balancing binary search tree (based on maximum y). We can add some metadata to this. Notably, since we try to maximize the rectangles intersected in the buffer, and keep looking for how the maximum changes as the buffer scans from left to right, we can consider the number of rectangles intersected if each rectangle in the buffer is the bottom-most rectangle.

If we can store the number of rectangles that is, we might be able to query it faster.

The solution is to store it in a different way, to reduce update costs. A binary search tree has a number of edges. Suppose each node should know how many rectangles can be intersected if that node is the bottom-most rectangle to be intersected. Instead, we can store the change in the number of rectangles intersected by the nodes on either side of each edge (call this the `diff`). For example, for the following tree (with min & max y of the rectangles):

```
     (3,4)
      / \
   (2,3) (5,6)
```

For `Rq` with a height of 2, if `(2,3)` is bottom-most, we can intersect 2 rectangles in total, for `(3,4)`, it is 2, and for `(5,6)`, it is 1.

Thus, the edges' `diff` can be 0 and -1, representing the change in the answer from child to parent.

Using the weights, we can quickly find the highest number, if each node also stores the maximum sum of a subpath in its subtree (call this `maxdiff`). For the leaves, it is 0, but for `(3,4)`, the maximum of 0 and -1 is 0, thus, we can store 0 as the maximum sum of the edges of a subpath in the root node.

We therefore know that the optimal answer is 0 more than the answer of the root node. We can find the answer of the root node, but keeping more metadata.

However, all this metadata can be queried and updated in `log n` time. This is because when we add a rectangle, adding it to the self balancing binary search tree takes `log n` time, as we may need to do up to `log n` rotations. When we do a rotation, we may need to update the weights on the edges, as well as `maxdiff` on the affected nodes - however this is `O(1)` for each rotation.

In addition, the effect of the extra rectangle on the `diff` of the edges needs to be updated. However, at most `O(log n)` edges must be updated, specifically, if we search the tree by the min y and max y of the new rectangle, we will find all the edges that need to be updated (although whether an edge that is traversed must be updated depends on whether we took the left or right child - some careful working is needed here to determine the exact rule).

Deleting a rectangle is just the reverse, so takes `O(log n)` time.

In this way, we can update the buffer in `O(log n)` time, and query it in `O(log n)` time, for an overall algorithmic complexity of `O(n log n)`.

**Note:** to find the maximum rectangles intersected in the buffer, we use `maxdiff`, which is the difference in answer between optimal, and that of the root node. To find the actual answer, we must find the difference between the answer of the lowest ordered rectangle in the binary search tree, and the root node. This is easily done in `O(log n)` time, by going down the left-most path, and summing up `diff` on the edges. Finally, find the answer on the lowest ordered rectangle. This is done by storing a 2nd self balancing binary search tree, ordered by minimum y. We can use this to find the number of rectangles intersected if the bottom-most rectangle is the lowest ordered rectangle when sorting by maximum y.

Update of this extra BST and querying also take `O(log n)` time, so this extra work does not change the overall complexity.

Comment: As far as I understand, that will work as a solution to the analogous 1d interval problem, however, I don´t see clearly how to incorporate the y-axis to the solution.

Comment: The x-coordinate is matched by what is currently in the buffer. The y-axis coordinates are matched by either iterating through everything in the buffer in a nested loop (the `O(n^2)` algorithm), or by using an interval tree to find how many rectangles currently in the buffer can be intersected - (note that even if you do not use an interval tree, you should still keep rectangles in the buffer sorted by minimum y coordinate to facilitate easy scanning)